# ui bootstrap datepicker with unix timestamps

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use ui-bootstrap datepicker binded to unix timestamp datas.

to do so, i would like to use [this directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15718899/2112538) which transforms the unix timestamp to a javascript date from ng-model.

[**here is the code (plunker)**](http://plnkr.co/edit/q2iSLN?p=preview)

```
<div ng-model="date" date-format>
    <datepicker min="minDate" show-weeks="false"></datepicker>
</div>
```

and the directive

```
  .directive('dateFormat', function() {
        return {
              require: 'ngModel',
              link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(function(timestamp) {
                          if (timestamp) return new Date( timestamp * 1000 );
                          else return "";
                    });
                    ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(date) {
                          if (date instanceof Date) return Math.floor( date.getTime() / 1000 ); 
                          else return "";
                    });
              }
        };
  })
```

it's possible to select a date. The unix timestamp is correct but then, the calendar switches to 1970…

is there a solution to make this work and use ui bootstrap's datepicker with unix timestamp datas ?

Answer (score 3):

It's kinda late, but I also had this problem - I don't want to keep additional value in my model just for datepicker/timepicker. Followed [this great tutorial on ngModelController](http://www.chroder.com/2014/02/01/using-ngmodelcontroller-with-custom-directives/) by Christopher Nadeau

This works in AngularJS 1.2.16:

```
.directive('timestampFormat', function() {
    // Directive that converts timestamp back and forth from
    // seconds to Date object
    return {
        scope: true, // isolated scope
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {

            ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
                // returns $viewValue
                return {
                    timestamp: (modelValue ? new Date(modelValue*1000) : "")
                };
            });

            scope.$watch('timestamp', function () {
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue({ timestamp: scope.timestamp });
            });

            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                // returns $modelValue
                if (viewValue.timestamp instanceof Date) return Math.floor( viewValue.timestamp.getTime() / 1000 );
                else return "";
            });

            ngModelCtrl.$render = function () {
                // renders timestamp to the view.
                if (!ngModelCtrl.$viewValue) ngModelCtrl.$viewValue = { timestamp: ""};
                scope.timestamp = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue.timestamp;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Now in view you can access it as a `timestamp` variable.

```
<div ng-model="yourModelValue" timestamp-format> 
  {{timestamp}}
  <timepicker ng-model="timestamp" ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

your don't need multiplied and divided

```
link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
          ngModelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(function(timestamp) {
            if (timestamp) {
              var date = new Date( timestamp );
              console.log('timestamp to date: ', date); 
              return date;
            }   else return "";
          });
          ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(date) {
            if (date instanceof Date) {
              timestamp = date.getTime();
              console.log('date to timestamp: ', timestamp);
              return timestamp; 
                } else return "";
          });
        }
```

Comment: if i do this the timestamp conversion is not correct anymore. (check here : [unix timestamp conversion](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/)