# AngularJs get Timestamp from a human readable date

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a way in angular JS to get Timestamp from a date obtained by a form?

```
<label for="start">From:</label>
<input type="date" ng-model="startDate" />
```

What will I have to write in the directive to transform this data? I didn't find anything about this particular issue,
Regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718203/dealing-with-transformed-data-in-angularjs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a directive to change the value from view to model.

http://jsfiddle.net/bateast/Q6py9/1/

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .directive('stringToTimestamp', function() {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, ele, attr, ngModel) {
                // view to model
                ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
                    return Date.parse(value);
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: how would I add a "model to view" conversion ?

Comment: Use ngModel.$formatter, you can check the docs here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Answer (score 9):

Since you are using input type as date, the string in model should be compatible with `Date` object in javascript. So you can do

`var timestamp = new Date($scope.startDate).getTime()`

Answer (score 2):

To use in a controller you can do something like this:

```
myApp.controller('TimestampCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.toTimestamp = function(date) {
    var dateSplitted = date.split('-'); // date must be in DD-MM-YYYY format
    var formattedDate = dateSplitted[1]+'/'+dateSplitted[0]+'/'+dateSplitted[2];
    return new Date(formattedDate).getTime();
  };
}]);
```

And can be used like this:

```
<div ng-controller="TimestampCtrl">
  The timestamp of <input ng-model="date"> is {{ toTimestamp(date) }}
</div>
```