# Date.now() not working in angularjs 1.3.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

i'm trying to get a local timestamp in a controller that won't be used in a view (ie filter not an option)
(for info it's to be written into an SQLite db as a local 'date created' field)

the following gets me the date - but is in the wrong format:

```
var current_time = new Date();
console.log('current_time:', current_time);
```

which gives me date in the format `current_time: Thu Dec 18 2014 23:16:27 GMT-0800 (PST)`

the following also works (which partially solves my problem - since i think i can use UTC):

```
var current_time = new Date().getTime();
console.log('current_time:', current_time);
```

which gives `current_time: 1418973515745` however it's UTC according to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

however this (which i thought was the solution) does not work:

```
var current_time = new Date.now();
console.log('current_time:', current_time);
```

gives me the following error:
`TypeError: function now() { [native code] } is not a constructor`

according to the javascript [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) I've got the right formats etc...
the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) don't mention anything specific (mostly seems to be how to get from timestamp to human readable, not the other way around)

so for curiosity:

- **is there any reason `Date.now()` shouldn't work in Angular?**  ..am I writing something wrong ?
- why would `Date().getTime()` work but `Date.now()` not ?
- **how do i get local js timestamp variable in Angular without using a filter ?**  ...and without using a separate longwinded directive as suggested in [AngularJs get Timestamp from a human readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677970/)

Comment: To save one character space, instead of doing `Date.now()`, you can do `+new Date` which is the same ;)

Comment: Both `new Date().getTime()` and `Date.now()` will return exactly the same value: milliseconds since the (UTC) epoch.

Comment: @RobG - yes you're right... read the docs again and there's UTC plain as day :-/  looks like I'll go with my UTC option :-)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫—but *Date.now()* should be more efficient as it doesn't create a Date instance, then do type conversion. The difference might be trivial, but so is saving 1 character. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use `new` with `Date.now()`, it's just:

```
var current_time = Date.now();
```

As the error message is telling you, `Date.now` isn't a constructor function.

Comment: wow you're quick - just figured it out... you get the points :-)

Answer (score 2):

rookie error:

it was the "new" that was causing the problem:
this works fine

```
var current_time = Date.now();
console.log('current_time:', current_time);
```

output = `current_time: 1418974955726`