# Using the same directive on multiple elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to follow the example from [this stackoverflow discussion on date formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474555/how-to-format-a-date-using-ng-model), it works very well for a page only has one single date field. However, if I have more than one date fields on the page, it seems like only **the first date field/ng-model will get set**, even other date fields are selected.

Below is the HTML template code:

```
    <div class="input-append" my-Datepickerloaded>
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.StartDate" my-Datepickerformater></input>
        <span class="add-on">
            <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
            </i>
        </span>
    </div>


    <div class="input-append" my-Datepickerloaded>
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.EndDate" my-Datepickerformater></input>
        <span class="add-on">
            <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
            </i>
        </span>
    </div>
```

And here is the directive code (**myDatePickerformater**):

```
return {
            require: '^ngModel',
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
                var moment = $window.moment,
                    dateFormat = 'MM/DD/YYYY';

                attrs.$observe('myDatepickerformater', function (newValue) {
                    ctrl.$modelValue = new Date(ctrl.$setViewValue);
                });

                ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (modelValue) {
                    scope = scope;
                    if (!dateFormat || !modelValue) return '';
                    var retVal = moment(modelValue).format(dateFormat);
                    return retVal;
                });

                ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                    scope = scope;
                    var date = moment(viewValue, dateFormat);
                    return (date && date.isValid() && date.year() > 1950) ? date.toDate() : "";
                });
            }
        };
```

I have tried to do a $scope.$watch on the models they bind to, it seems like even if I am changing the **user.EndDate** input field, it is always **user.StartDate** gets the change and **user.EndDate** remain untouched, even if the "input" field is displaying both fields correctly.

How do I make sure both fields will get their bind model updated correctly?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: You need to give your directive an `isolated scope` - right now, multiple instances of the directive are sharing the same scope, so updating your model is not working as expected. Take a look at http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: @AlexOsborn You should write that up as an answer to make it more obvious that this isn't unresolved. It was the solution for me.

Answer (score 6):

You need to give your directive an `isolated scope`.

Right now, multiple instances of the directive are sharing the same scope, so updating your model is not working as expected.

Take a look at [docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

```
require: '^ngModel',
restrict: 'A',
scope: {
    ...
},
link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
    ....
```