# How do I format data in a view in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-view

`<input type="text" ng-model="user.User.DateOfBirth">` is in my view. `user.User.DateOfBirth` is currently in `YYYYMMDD` format, but I want it to show as `mm/dd/yyyy` format in the view. Is it possible to convert this just for the display?

Comment: Use a custom filter. `{{user.User.DateOfBirth | date[:format]}}`

Comment: well detailed method here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474555/how-to-format-a-date-using-ng-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For outputting the data in the correct format try filters (in your case the date filter: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:date)

Well, for inputs that's another case. I guess you could always bind that input to another property, watch that and parse it yourself and then assign it to your real model...

Some more insight, you could try something like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myDateInput">
```

In your JS controller use the following:

```
$scope.$watch('myDateInput', function (newValue) {
    $scope.user.User.DateOfBirth = $filter('date')(newValue, 'yyyy-MM-dd'); // Or whatever format your real model should use
});

$scope.$watch('user.User.DateOfBirth', function (newValue) {
    $scope.myDateInput = $filter('date')(newValue, 'yyyy-MM-dd'); // Or whatever format your input should use
});
```

It would probably be better though to force the user to use a certain input format, either by some sort of pattern matching (and therefore validation) or by some sort of special date input/widget.

Comment: My `user.User.DateOfBirth` isn't a valid JS date object

Comment: It doesn't have to be an object, it can be a string: taken from the Angular date filter docs: `Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number) or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats`

Comment: I get: `Expression 'user.User.DateOfBirth | date: 'medium'' is non-assignable. Element: <input ng-model="user.User.DateOfBirth | date: 'medium'" type="text">`

Comment: don't put the filter in your `ng-model` directive

Comment: then how do i do it in an input box?

Comment: I added some code, I haven't tested it though, but it might work. Or just use it as inspiration ;)

Answer (score 4):

This also may help you

http://jsfiddle.net/mikeeconroy/Hu9m2/1/

```
.filter('myFormatDateFilter',function(){
    return function(input){
        if(angular.isDefined(input)){
           if(input.length >= 8){
                input = input.slice(0,8);

                input = input.slice(4,6) + '/' + input.slice(6,8) + '/' + input.slice(0,4);
            }
        }
        return input;
    };
});
```