# how to change the format of date into dd/mm/year

Tags: html, angularjs

In this html code date format is mm/dd/year but i want dd/mm/year format.

```
 <label>LAUNCH DATE</label><br>
<h4><input type="date" placeholder="Launch date" name="date" class="form-control"
ng-model="user.date" required></h4><br>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a date using ng-model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474555/how-to-format-a-date-using-ng-model)

Comment: used to this filter | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'

Comment: try this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: i don't want to format the date ,i want to show input date type must be in dd/mm/year format.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way possible to change the format in `input[type=date]` if your want to change it than you can used to other library as like **jquery ui library**

According to **[@David Walschots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519493/1365428)**