# How to show splitted date from database

Tags: javascript, angularjs

actually the date is stored in this format in my db 
**2016-04-01 00:00:00**
Now the thing is in listing i just want to show **2016-04-01** this part . 
i am using angularJS   and php . I don't want to change db date format. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please see the [angular date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: just `select date(dateColumn)` in your query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a date using ng-model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474555/how-to-format-a-date-using-ng-model)

Comment: well you need to post some code, although this can be done `date.split(' ')[0];`

Comment: actually i am rendering this date directly from the database in ngtable now just want to show only this part 2016-04-01 in ngtable

Comment: As I mentioned above see the angular date filter. This is compatible with ngTable (which is also Angular). If you want more help post your ngtable html fragment.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an angular filter for your dates.

[Angular doc for the date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.