# <mdp-time-picker> not updating ng-model value

Tags: angularjs, datetimepicker, mdp

I have my code as below

Inside controller :

```
 $scope.starttime = '10:00';
```

Inside html

```
<div  layout="column" style="margin-left: 177px">
                          <mdp-time-picker aria-label="{{starttime}}" ng-
      model="starttime" ng-disabled="disabled"></mdp-time-picker>

 </div>
```

Althought, in HTMl i can view {{starttime}} displaying 10:00, why its not attaching to mdp-time-picker ?

Answer (score 0):

It should have proper time format,

```
  $scope.starttime  = new Date();
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/sajeetharan/pen/POeeZY)

Comment: I need to display it in 24 hours format and not with AM / PM

Comment: you need to use a directive https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474555/how-to-format-a-date-using-ng-model