# Date format with mvc date object not working with Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I am binding mvc + json object with input control, but date is not formatting correctly

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.GetInitialData = function () {
        $(".load-bar").show();  

        $http({
            method: "get",
            url: "/ProjectClosure/GetInitialData"
        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.projectData = response.data.projectData;           
        }, function () {
            alert("Error Occur");
        });
    };

});


<input type="datetime" class="form-control" name="CompletionDate" required placeholder="@ProjectResources.CompletionDate" ng-model="projectData.CompletionDate | date:'dd MMM yyyy'">
```

I expect date in 20 Aug 2019 format but it is displaying /Date(1566495000000)/

Comment: Using the date pipe inside an ng-model expression makes no sense. The expression must be assignable for 2-wau binding to work. Angular can do `projectData.CompletionDate = newEnteredValue`. But it can't do `projectData.CompletionDate | date:'dd MMM yyyy' = newValue`.

Comment: And the date filter doesn't support strings such as `/Date(1566495000000)/` anyway. Read its documentation. Use a decent, standard date format. (i.e. ISO-8601)

Comment: check this question maybe can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474555/how-to-format-a-date-using-ng-model

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no `input type="datetime"` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Form_%3Cinput%3E_types
2. This would need yyyy-mm-dd format as value and displays it depending on locale
3. If you need time use `input type="datetime-locale"`, but take a look at browser support first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local